# Do twig macros work with Gulp Twig?

Tags: gulp, twig

Im using twig but its being run via gulp not symphony. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-twig

Ive used extends and includes successfully but I cant get macros to work. Do macros require symphony?

In my main twig file I have:

```
{% import test.twig as myMacros %}

{{ myMacros.printProducts(products, 'this is a test') }}
```

In test.twig:

```
{% macro printProducts(products) %}
  <h1>{{ products }}</h1>
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a syntax issue.

In the main file:

```
{% import "test.twig" as myMacros %}

{{ myMacros.printProducts('this is a test') }}
```

In test.twig:

```
{% macro printProducts(products) %}
  <h1>{{ products }}</h1>
{% endmacro %}
```

Implementation Notes:

https://github.com/justjohn/twig.js/wiki/Implementation-Notes